# LWC Create and Dispatch Event Does Not Work

Tags: salesforce-lightning, lwc

Attempting to simulate a mouse click on one button, by clicking on another button.  The goal is to reuse the behavior of a single custom button throughout the page.  Why is the `dispatchEvent` not working?

How can a click on `<c-custom-button>` be simulated?

parentApp.html

```
<template>
    <div>
        <c-custom-button
            label="New">
        </c-custom-button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <lightning-button
            label="Call New"
            onclick={simulateClick}>
        </lightning-button>
    </div>
</template>
```

parentApp.js

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

    cButtonElement;

    simulateClick() {
        this.cButtonElement = this.template.querySelector('c-custom-button');
        let clickEvent = new CustomEvent('click');
        this.cButtonElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
    }

}
```

customButton.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-button
        label={label}
        icon-name="utility:new"
        onclick={handleClick}>
    </lightning-button>
</template>
```

customButton.js

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @api label;

    handleClick() {
        this.label = 'CLICKED!'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Nathan Shulman for helping with this](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000LlT2&fId=0D54S000008Gtd5&s1oid=00D4S0000019iJX&s1nid=0DB30000000072L&emkind=chatterCommentNotification&s1uid=0053000000A9OG7&emtm=1598644390501&fromEmail=1&s1ext=0).

Add call to child method in parentApp.js

```
    simulateClick() {
        this.cButtonElement = this.template.querySelector('c-custom-button');
        this.cButtonElement.handleClick();
    }
```

Add @api decorator to method in customButton.js

```
    @api handleClick() {         
        this.label = 'CLICKED!'
    }
```